# LibPng Background

Tags: c++, libpng

Ok so in photoshop, I created an 8-bit Colour image with a transparent background and some text. I then created an image that is 16-bit Colour with transparent background and some text.

When I right click both images and go to the properties, it shows 32 bitdepth for both :l
So I decide to read the image with LibPng using the following settings:

```
typedef union RGB     //Holds all the pixels..
{
    uint32_t Color;
    struct
    {
        unsigned char B, G, R, A;
    } RGBA;
} *PRGB;


channels = png_get_channels(PngPointer, InfoPointer);
    png_get_IHDR(PngPointer, InfoPointer, &width, &height, &bitdepth, &colortype, &interlacetype, nullptr, nullptr);
    png_set_interlace_handling(PngPointer);
    png_set_strip_16(PngPointer);
    png_set_packing(PngPointer);

    switch (colortype)
    {
        case PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY:
        {
            png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8(PngPointer);
            png_set_expand(PngPointer);
            png_set_bgr(PngPointer);
            break;
        }

        case PNG_COLOR_TYPE_PALETTE:
        {
            png_set_palette_to_rgb(PngPointer);
            if (png_get_valid(PngPointer, InfoPointer, PNG_INFO_tRNS))
                png_set_tRNS_to_alpha(PngPointer);
            png_set_filler(PngPointer, 0xFF, PNG_FILLER_AFTER);
            png_set_bgr(PngPointer);
        BitsPerPixel = 24;
            break;
        }

        case PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY_ALPHA:
        {
            png_set_gray_to_rgb(PngPointer);
            break;
        }

        case PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB:
        {
            png_set_bgr(PngPointer);
            png_set_filler(PngPointer, 0xFF, PNG_FILLER_AFTER);
            BitsPerPixel = 24;
            break;
        }

        case PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGBA:
        {
            png_set_bgr(PngPointer);
            BitsPerPixel = 32;
            break;
        }

        default: png_destroy_read_struct(&PngPointer, &InfoPointer, nullptr); throw std::runtime_error("Error: Png Type not supported."); break;
    }

    //SET BACKGROUND
    /*png_color_16 my_background, *image_background;
    my_background.red = 255;
    my_background.green = 255;
    my_background.blue = 255;
    image_background = &my_background;

    if (png_get_bKGD(PngPointer, InfoPointer, &image_background))
    {
        png_set_filler(PngPointer, 0xFF, PNG_FILLER_AFTER);
        png_set_background(PngPointer, image_background, PNG_BACKGROUND_GAMMA_FILE, 1, 1.0);
    }
    else
    {
        png_set_filler(PngPointer, 0xFF, PNG_FILLER_AFTER);
        png_set_background(PngPointer, &my_background, PNG_BACKGROUND_GAMMA_SCREEN, 0, 1.0);
    }*/
    //END SET BACKGROUND

    png_read_update_info(PngPointer, InfoPointer);
    channels = png_get_channels(PngPointer, InfoPointer);
    png_get_IHDR(PngPointer, InfoPointer, &width, &height, &bitdepth, &colortype, &interlacetype, nullptr, nullptr);
```

My settings for saving are:

```
png_set_write_fn(PngPointer, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&hFile), WriteToStream, nullptr);
    png_set_IHDR (PngPointer, InfoPointer, width, height, bitdepth, BitsPerPixel == 24 ? PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB : PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGBA, PNG_INTERLACE_NONE, PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_DEFAULT, PNG_FILTER_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    png_write_info(PngPointer, InfoPointer);

    png_set_bgr(PngPointer);
    png_set_packing(PngPointer);
    png_set_interlace_handling(PngPointer);
    if (colortype == PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB) png_set_filler(PngPointer, 0xFF, PNG_FILLER_AFTER);
```

The PNG looks like:
[image]

When I save it as a bitmap via C++, it looks like (8 bit one does this): [image]

Saving it back as a PNG, it looks exactly like the original. Both the 8 and 16 save back fine.

The thing is, if I Uncomment that "SetBackground" Section, it works perfectly saving as bitmap EXCEPT that when I save it back as PNG, the background is no longer transparent due to the code setting it to white (255, 255, 255).

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you're using `png_set_tRNS_to_alpha` you shouldn't use `png_set_filler` (use `png_set_filler` only if image doesn't include transparency). And, when you apply `png_set_filler` to a RGB image you get a 32 bpp image, so _BitsPerPixel_ should be **32**

Comment: Problem. I need to know how to detect whether there is an alpha channel or not. That way I can set the background white and when saving it back to PNG, set it back to transparent.

I did do what you suggested though. That didn't fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I made some changes to your code. **Not tested!**

```
channels = png_get_channels(PngPointer, InfoPointer);
png_get_IHDR(PngPointer, InfoPointer, &width, &height, &bitdepth, &colortype, &interlacetype, nullptr, nullptr);
png_set_interlace_handling(PngPointer);
png_set_strip_16(PngPointer);
png_set_packing(PngPointer);
bool BGneeded = (colortype > PNG_COLOR_TYPE_PALETTE); 
switch (colortype)
{
    case PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY:
    {
        png_set_expand_gray_1_2_4_to_8(PngPointer);
        //png_set_expand(PngPointer);
        //png_set_bgr(PngPointer);  //R=G=B so there's no need to swap RGB values
        png_set_gray_to_rgb(PngPointer);
        break;
    }

    case PNG_COLOR_TYPE_PALETTE:
    {
        png_set_palette_to_rgb(PngPointer);
        if (png_get_valid(PngPointer, InfoPointer, PNG_INFO_tRNS))
        {
            png_set_tRNS_to_alpha(PngPointer);
            BGneeded = true;
        }
        else
            png_set_filler(PngPointer, 0xFF, PNG_FILLER_AFTER);
        png_set_bgr(PngPointer);
        BitsPerPixel = 32;
        break;
    }

    case PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY_ALPHA:
    {
        png_set_gray_to_rgb(PngPointer);
        break;
    }

    case PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB:
    {
        png_set_bgr(PngPointer);
        png_set_filler(PngPointer, 0xFF, PNG_FILLER_AFTER);
        BitsPerPixel = 32;
        break;
    }

    case PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGBA:
    {
        png_set_bgr(PngPointer);
        BitsPerPixel = 32;
        break;
    }

    default: png_destroy_read_struct(&PngPointer, &InfoPointer, nullptr); throw std::runtime_error("Error: Png Type not supported."); break;
}

//SET BACKGROUND
png_color_16 my_background;
png_color_16p image_background;

my_background.red = 255;
my_background.green = 255;
my_background.blue = 255;

if (png_get_bKGD(PngPointer, InfoPointer, &image_background))
    png_set_background(PngPointer, image_background, PNG_BACKGROUND_GAMMA_FILE, 1, 1.0);
else if (BGneeded)
    png_set_background(PngPointer, &my_background, PNG_BACKGROUND_GAMMA_SCREEN, 0, 1.0);
//END SET BACKGROUND

png_read_update_info(PngPointer, InfoPointer);
channels = png_get_channels(PngPointer, InfoPointer);
png_get_IHDR(PngPointer, InfoPointer, &width, &height, &bitdepth, &colortype, &interlacetype, nullptr, nullptr);
```

Comment: This works. Except, when saving back to PNG, the background will be white. I was trying to save it back as an exact copy of the loaded image. Thanks for trying though.